# Trying to align 3 images within a container - poss float issue?

Tags: css, containers

I am trying to float left, middle and right three images (the images have a bottom and top layer, with mouse over hover) within a container. The right image for some reason will not co-operate and whatever I try keeps on falling below the other two images.

The container width is 1200px and the images are each 385px x 385px

I have entered a height value for the container but this doesn't help - infact I have tried just about everything...

My CSS is as follows:

```
   .container { overflow: hidden;
    width:1200px; 
    }
    #cf385 {
    position:relative;
    height:385px;
    width:385px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    #cf385 img {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    height:385px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #cf385 img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
```

My HTML is:

```
    <center>
<div class="container">
<div style="float: left;">
<div id="cf385" onclick="location.href='hold.html';">
<img class="bottom"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-       images-to-delete/test385on.png" width="385px" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" />
<img class="top"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385off.png" width="385px" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" />
</div></div>
<div style="float: none;">
<div id="cf385" onclick="location.href='hold.html';">
<img class ="bottom"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385on.png" width="385px" style="right: -10px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" />
<img class="top"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385off.png" width="385px" style="right: -10px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"/>
</div></div>
<div style="float: right;">
<div id="cf385" onclick="location.href='hold.html';">
<img class="bottom"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385on.png" width="385px" style="right: 0px; top: 0px;" />
<img class="top"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385off.png" width="385px" style="right: 0px; top: 0px;"/>
</div></div>
</div>

    </center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing float:none to float:left;

```
float:none;
```

seems to mess up other floats when used on the same page.

Alternatively you could show the divs/images using

```
display:inline-block;
```

which will align then adjacent to each other if you give them a defined height and width.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Don! I floated the second Div left and then adjusted the =style left: to 27px (took a bit of fiddling) but this now works like a dream. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Don's method or you can use this

HTML

```
<center>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <div id="cf385" onclick="location.href='hold.html';">
                <img class="bottom"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-       images-to-delete/test385on.png" width="385px" style="left: 0px; top: 0px" />
                <img class="top"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385off.png" width="385px" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <div id="cf385" onclick="location.href='hold.html';">
                <img class ="bottom"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385on.png" width="385px" style="right: -10px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" />
                <img class="top"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385off.png" width="385px" style="right: -10px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <div id="cf385" onclick="location.href='hold.html';">
                <img class="bottom"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385on.png" width="385px" />
                <img class="top"alt="del" height="385px" longdesc="del" src="images/Test-images-to-delete/test385off.png" width="385px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

CSS

```
.container { 
    overflow: hidden;
    width:1200px; 
}
.imageContainer{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.imageContainer:first-child{    
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#cf385 {
    position:relative;
    height:385px;
    width:385px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#cf385 img {
    height:385px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}    
#cf385 img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

I've also cleared your inline styles and put the styles in the css file so your HTML stays clean.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2FPAZ/

p.s. You do not need the `<center>` tags to get the same result, you could remove these.

Comment: Hi Jop, I tried this method also. It did work in so much as the divs all lined up as they should, but I lost the transition functionality. Bit weird. Thanks for your help!